# How can i place a newly generated pagination link data into a new div element

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

please i need some help on how i can append a pagination link data to the current page.

Lets say i have the following pagination links: [1][2][3] and i am currently on the page http://127.0.0.1/link?page1

I want it to be that when i click [2] the data from [2] is appended to the current page and when i click [3] the data from [3] is also append to the current page without any of the data on the current page changing.

I would also like it not to load any specific loaded page twice.

Here is what i have tried:

```
$(document).on('click', '.pagination a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var page = $(this).attr('href');
    getOffersPage(page);

    function getOffersPage(page) {
        if (page === page) {
            var resultSection = $('#new-result');
            $('.appended-data').load(page + ' #new-result', function() {
                $('#paginated-links').addClass('text-right x1-margin-top');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you thought about just generating the page from data? It seems you're currently trying to load the entire page into `.appended-data` by using `jQuery.load`.

Comment: Actually i am loading a section of the page "#result".
But then how would i do it if i wanted to use your method?

Comment: @David it seems like you're wanting to use ajax. Any time you direct the page to a new link, it's going to reload. Do you know much about ajax?

Comment: I wouldn't say i know much on ajax.
Still learning it.

Comment: @David Yeah, you're right. Didn't see that part in the docs. The approach I'm talking about is what you typically use in frameworks like Angular, React, and Vue. [Here's a list rendering example in Vue](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html). You store your data in a component and then dynamically render each element. This of course assumes that you have a backend which paginates and serves your data. Just a heads up though, I think you are basically trying to implement _lazy loading_ and there are a couple of jQuery plugins for that out there.

Comment: Okay..
Let me check for some plugins but after i have checked out the link you pasted.
Thanks! @FK82

Comment: @David I fleshed out my comment a little and added an example of a basic lazy loading component with Vue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's an example how to generate elements from data using Vue JS. As you can see, the snippet simply generates a paragraph for each number in an array containing the numbers 1 to 20. We have two buttons to lazily load more respectively less content.

A major benefit of using Vue (or React, or Angular) is that the [reactivity](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) meachanism makes sure that changes to the model (in this case changes to `page` upon pressing *more* or *less*) are detected and trigger re-rendering.

```js
const items = []
for (i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  items[i - 1] = i
}

new Vue({
  el: '#lazy-load-example',
  data: {
    items,
    page: 1,
    pageSize: 5,
  },
  methods: {
    itemsForPage() {
      const N = this.page * this.pageSize
      return this.items.slice(0, Math.min(N, this.items.length))
    },
    onMore() {
      const N = this.Page * this.pageSize
      if (this.hasMore()) {
        this.page++
      }
    },
    onLess() {
      if (this.page > 1) {
        this.page--
      }
    },
    hasMore() {
      return this.page < this.items.length / this.pageSize;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    .as-console-wrapper { display: none !important; }
</style>

<div class="card d-flex flex-column" id="lazy-load-example">
  <div class="card-body d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
    <h2 class="card-title">Lazy Load Example</h2>
    <div class="col-12"><p v-for="item in itemsForPage()" class="col-3">item: {{ item }} </p></div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-footer d-flex">
    <div class="mr-2"><button class="btn btn-primary" :disabled="page === 1"  v-on:click="onLess">Less</button></div>
    <div><button class="btn btn-primary" :disabled="!hasMore()"  v-on:click="onMore">More</button></div>
  </div>
</div>
```